# How to reduce logs from database cleaner in ruby application

Tags: ruby, rspec, database-cleaner

Here is my ruby spec_helper for rspec:

[image]

As you see I'm using database cleaner because I'm writing tests using the DB.

However, I get all this nonsense in my console output:

[image]

Is there a way to supress some of this output? Again remember, I'm not in RAils so I can't simply do:

`config.logger.level = Logger::ERROR`

Comment: You can set the `database_cleaner` looger in configuration https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/blob/master/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb#L52 but it defaults level to `Logger::ERROR` anyway so I am not sure what your intentions are

Comment: On a sidenote seems likely that this is rspec output and not database_cleaner but if you are suing `ActiveRecord` then you can use `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil`